# puppeteer is efficient or node-crawler?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, node-crawler

First of all I know difference between web crawler and web automation tools.

I am running a crawler that involves fetching data from a specific domain.I will try to explain the scenario.

Step 1 :
Run chrome headless with puppeeter and go to the domain.

Step 2:
Type a search key word and press enter . wait for the result and gather array of search result and extract links from the array.

Step 3 :
For each link create new page and go to the link.and wait for the page to be loaded and then extract data from it.

For the requirement of the project this steps must be run parallel in nodejs. So I desided to use [cluster nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)
.I tried to distubute the links between workers with send message through event emmiter.

The bottleneck :

Each worker needs to run instance of puppeteer again and create new page and go to the link and do the crawling stuff.

Here comes the problem.this is big cost I think if every worker run a instance of pupeeter, and puppeteer it self runs a chrome instance in it.

So I came with a much simple solution: using a [node-crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler) package not a automation tools like puppeteer or selenium .
But in my case. The domain I need to crawl has a problem. The data I need to crawl is not ready , cuase it came from ajax call and crawler cannot detect the data.

So my question is :

First question: Is it possible to make puppeteer efficient for performance in cluster mode?

Second question :

If i use [node-crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler) how can I tell that wait for data came from ajax call ?

Comment: Did you try Puppeteer Cluster?

Comment: @hardkoded tnx alot this is a huge help for me.

Comment: Anything that doesn't use chromium will be more efficient, but often can't do modern websites easily.